# Way to loop over multiple tables and keep only if condition met?

Tags: r, loops, data.table, combinations, nested-loops

So I'm working on project that has multiple data tables, separated by month, that I need to iterate through. Speed is of the essence here, and I can't seem to get the time down to something reasonable unless I do a lot of crossjoins through data table functions. So here are my tables:

TABLE 1

```
Product Date        Cost
A       8/1/2020    10
A       8/2/2020    20
A       8/3/2020    30
B       8/4/2020    15
B       8/5/2020    25
B       8/6/2020    35
```

and TABLE 2:

```
Product Date    Price
A       9/1/2020    20
A       9/2/2020    30
A       9/3/2020    40
B       9/4/2020    27
B       9/5/2020    33
B       9/6/2020    42
```

So I need to iterate over every combination of Table 2 Price - Table 1 Cost, and do it by Product. So output would be:

NEW TABLE

```
Product Date1         Date2          Profit
A       8/1/2020      9/1/2020       10
A       8/1/2020      9/2/2020       20
...
```

EDIT: To clarify, the New Table should continue on. Product A should have 27 different profits (3 dates under A x 3 dates under A x 3 discount rates) assuming they are all above 0. If any of the profits are below 0, then I don't want them as part of the New Table.

I also have a Discount factor I need to apply to each permutation of Price as we give discounts quite a bit

```
Discount = c(10%,12%,18%)
```

I've tried using a loop and various ways of using apply but the loops take way too long to finish (hours, and some never do). The combinations lead to millions of rows but I only want to keep the profitable ones, where Price*Discount > Cost, which are only maybe 10,000 in number.

My solution is to cross join the data tables to create a massive table that I can vectorize against, which is much faster (around 1 min) but with some of the larger tables I quickly run into memory constraints and it isn't very scalable.

```
CTbl =setkey(CTbl[,c(k=1,.SD)],k)[Price[,c(k=1,.SD)],allow.cartesian=TRUE][,k:=NULL]
CTbl[,Profit:=(Discount*Price - Cost]
CTbl = setDT(CTbl)[, .SD[Price > Cost ]]
DT = CTbl[,list(MinProfit = min(Profit)),by = Product]
```

Of course this is quite fast but is a huge of waste of memory when all I really want is profitable rows, and of course the ongoing memory issue.

Can anyone help? I've asked some R users at work but they seem stumped as well, the loops they made couldn't get close to the sub-5 minutes it takes to run the above. I don't mind a bit of extra time if it means I can scale it up.

Thanks!

Comment: Why you only have two dates? A has three cost values and three prices so the new table should have three profits. Is that right? Also having three dates is correct?

Comment: It's a bit odd that a result with only millions of rows is taking that long -- R is built to handle data of that size and much larger. Have you tried parallelizing some of these for-loops? Converting them to `foreach` syntax is usually not too. difficut

Comment: It should iterate through the Date from Table 1 and Dates from Table 2 and get every combination, then afterward see the product groups profit. So by the end of it, Product A should have 27 total Profits recorded (8/1/2020 and 9/1/2020, 8/1/2020 and 9/2/2020...to...8/6/2020 and 9/6/2020 for each of the 3 discount rates). If any of the Profits < 0 then I don't include them in the new data table, so if only 3 are greater than 0 then I only keep those three along with the date from Table 1 and date from Table 2. @Duck

Comment: @WalkerHarrison I've tried that but it still took much longer than the data table solution above. Maybe my data table looping was inefficient? I did DT[[i]] type looping syntax, is there a more DT way to do it?

Comment: Sorry I should correct my comment above, meant that for Product A ends at 8/3/2020 and 9/3/2020

Comment: maybe try to use a non-equi join to limit the number of results. e.g. `DT2[, paste0("Disc", 1L:length(Discount)) := lapply(Discount, function(k) Price * k)]
;rbindlist(lapply(paste0("Cost<Disc", 1L:length(Discount)), function(x) DT1[DT2, on=c("Product", x)]), use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)`. But since its permutations, i dont think you can shrink the number of results by much

Comment: @chinsoon12 Hey that led me down some paths on non-equi joins in data table and turns out you can iterate by row using the 'by=.EACHI' argument, so combining your answer with that of Arun's answer here: [EACHI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38297710/14033843) means I'm getting closer! Thank you! Trying to still put it all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem for the `dplyr` package, which. The `dplyr` package allows you to string together data operations in a "pipe" to avoid storing things in memory. The pipe operator `%>%`takes the output of the function on the left and uses it as the first argument of the function on the right. Each function in the `dplyr` package works over the entire vector or data tibble, so no need for loops.

So, your operation might look like the following:

```
# Initialize random data like your first table
df1 <- data.frame(product = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10000, replace = TRUE),
              date1 = sample(seq(as.Date("2020/08/01"), as.Date("2020/08/31"), 
                                 by = "day"), 10000, replace = TRUE),
              cost = round(runif(10000, 5, 100)))
# Initialize random data like your second table 
df2 <- data.frame(product = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10000, replace = TRUE),
              date2 = sample(seq(as.Date("2020/09/01"), as.Date("2020/09/30"), 
                                 by = "day"), 10000, replace = TRUE),
              price = round(runif(10000, 5, 100)))
# Initialize discounts 
discounts <- data.frame(product = rep(LETTERS[1:10],4), 
                    discount = rep(c(0, 0.1, 0.12, 0.18), 10))
library(dplyr)
out_table <- df1 %>%
  full_join(df2) %>%
  full_join(discounts) %>%
  mutate(profit = price * discount - cost) %>%
  filter(profit > 0)
```

For my random data, this takes about 3 seconds on my machine. Furthermore, the `filter` verb only keeps those rows we want.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Norris, this is actually very fast but I still run into memory problems, primarily because dplyr does a full equi-join prior to the filtering step. The tables I'm using are rather large, but this is a great way to restructure my code.

Comment: So it looks like to get exactly what I want, I will need to use sqldf or some data.table formulation I need to investigate further, but your answer is the fastest/closest to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer to your question, but maybe you can iterate a loop by *product*s. The following function finds profits for a specified product. The function does not include *discount* but it can be added if the function works as you want.

```
profit = function(product, df1, df2) {

    cost = with(df1, df1[which(Product == product), 'Cost'])
    price = with(df2, df2[which(Product == product), 'Price'])
    date = merge(
            with(df1, df1[which(Product == product), 'Date']), 
            (with(df2, df2[which(Product == product), 'Date']))
            )
    product = t(matrix(rep(price, length(cost)), nrow = length(cost)) - t(matrix(rep(cost, length(price)), ncol = length(price))))
    product = data.frame(cbind(date[which(product > 0), ], product[which(product > 0)]))
    names(product) = c('costdate', 'pricedate', 'profit')
    return(product)

}
```

Example:

```
df1 = data.frame(Product = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'), 
                Date = c('8/1/2020', '8/2/2020', '8/3/2020', '8/4/2020', '8/5/2020', '8/6/2020'),
                Cost = c(10, 20, 30, 15, 25, 35))
df2 = data.frame(Product = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'), 
                Date = c('9/1/2020', '9/2/2020', '9/3/2020', '9/4/2020', '9/5/2020', '9/6/2020'),
                Price = c(20, 30, 40, 27, 33, 42))

> profit('A', df1, df2)
  costdate pricedate profit
1 8/1/2020  9/1/2020     10
4 8/1/2020  9/2/2020     20
5 8/2/2020  9/2/2020     10
7 8/1/2020  9/3/2020     30
8 8/2/2020  9/3/2020     20
9 8/3/2020  9/3/2020     10
> profit('B', df1, df2)

  costdate pricedate profit
1 8/4/2020  9/4/2020     12
2 8/5/2020  9/4/2020      2
4 8/4/2020  9/5/2020     18
5 8/5/2020  9/5/2020      8
7 8/4/2020  9/6/2020     27
8 8/5/2020  9/6/2020     17
9 8/6/2020  9/6/2020      7
```

I could not test it properly since I have limited data.

Comment: Thanks! I had to remove a couple of parenthesis on the matrix part but the code works well and has given me an idea to break up the tables into smaller chunks, process them, then bind after the fact. Let me work with this a bit more to see the speed of it on large data tables.

Comment: So the speed and memory is still an issue as I use it on larger tables, primarily because the function does a join and then filters out profit above 0 rather than increment join row by row and keep only those above 0. But the idea is sound and may be what I have to do in the end, break up the tables into more manageable chunks and bind in the end.

Comment: I am glad to hear that. Good luck.